# Examine disk usage of file tree, accounting for reflinks on Btrfs

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, btrfs

Calculation of disk usage through `du` entails maintaining a set of all inodes represented by files under the tree, such that hard links will be counted only once with respect to total disk usage.

However, if separate inodes on a Btrfs system share the same underlying extents on the file system through reflinks, then `du` will still treat them as completely separate, counting the total disk usage as the sum of the sizes for each inode. Thus, the same extent will be counted for as many files as use it.

Is any utility available that will examine the reflinks of all files in a directory tree to compute an accurate estimate of disk usage within a Btrfs system?

Comment: In short: `btrfs fi du`. See `man 8 btrfs-filesystem`.

Comment: @Kamil, the reference may provide information answering the question, but the phrasing of the referenced question is not inclusive of the case I described.